# How can I improve my count distinct for data stream implementation in Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have this program in Flink (Java) which count the distinct words in a data stream. I implemented using the example of count words and them I applied another window with the same time to evaluate the distinct values. The program is working fine. However, I am concerned that I am using two windows to process a distinct count. The first window counts the number of words and the second window I switch the number of words to be `1` and the word to be the second element of a `Tuple2`. Them I count the number of keys. This is the input and out put of my program:

```
// input:
aaa
aaa
bbb
ccc
bbb
aaa
output:
(3,bbb-ccc-aaa)
```

If I remove the second window it shows all the evaluating for each key and saves the state of the previous window.

```
// input:
aaa
aaa
bbb
ccc
bbb
aaa
// output:
3> (1,bbb)
3> (2,bbb-aaa)
3> (3,bbb-aaa-ccc)
// wait the first window to be evaluated.
// input:
aaa
aaa
bbb
ccc
bbb
aaa
// output:
3> (4,bbb-aaa-ccc-ccc)
3> (5,bbb-aaa-ccc-ccc-bbb)
3> (6,bbb-aaa-ccc-ccc-bbb-aaa)
```

My program:

```
public class WordCountDistinctSocketFilterQEP {
    public WordCountDistinctSocketFilterQEP() throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // @formatter:off
        env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000)
                .flatMap(new SplitterFlatMap())
                .keyBy(new MyKeySelector())
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .reduce(new CountReduceFunction())
                .map(new SwapMapFunction())
                .keyBy(0)
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5))) // TESTING REMOVING THIS WINDOW
                .reduce(new CountDistinctFunction())
                .print();
        // @formatter:on

        String executionPlan = env.getExecutionPlan();
        System.out.println("ExecutionPlan ........................ ");
        System.out.println(executionPlan);
        System.out.println("........................ ");
        // dataStream.print();

        env.execute("WordCountDistinctSocketFilterQEP");
    }

    public static class SwapMapFunction implements MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<Integer, String>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5148172163266330182L;

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, String> map(Tuple2<String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
            return Tuple2.of(1, value.f0);
        }
    }

    public static class SplitterFlatMap implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3121588720675797629L;

        @Override
        public void flatMap(String sentence, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, 1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyKeySelector implements KeySelector<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2787589690596587044L;

        @Override
        public String getKey(Tuple2<String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
            return value.f0;
        }
    }

    public static class CountReduceFunction implements ReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8541031982462158730L;

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> reduce(Tuple2<String, Integer> value1, Tuple2<String, Integer> value2)
                throws Exception {
            return Tuple2.of(value1.f0, value1.f1 + value2.f1);
        }
    }

    public static class CountDistinctFunction implements ReduceFunction<Tuple2<Integer, String>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7077952757215699563L;

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, String> reduce(Tuple2<Integer, String> value1, Tuple2<Integer, String> value2)
                throws Exception {
            return Tuple2.of(value1.f0 + value2.f0, value1.f1 + "-" + value2.f1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReduceFunctions` work better with `Collections` (`Maps`, `Lists`, **`Sets`**). If you Map every word into a one element `Set`, you could write a `ReduceFunction` that operates on `Set<String>` and then you could do it with one `ReduceFunction` instead of two.

So have `splitterFlatMap` return a series of one element long `Set<String>`, `MyKeySelector` returns the first element of each set. The window function is fine, change the reduce function to match the `Set<String>` type, with the guts of the function just being `value1.addAll(value2)`. At this point you've got the set of all unique words in the input, spread across however many parallel tasks you're running. Depending on where you're putting all this data when you're finished, that may be sufficient. Otherwise, you could put a global window on the end of that, and use the same reduce function again (explanation below)

Your second problem is that this won't scale as is. In part, that's more of a philosophical problem. You can't really get a global count across parallel instance without having every parallel instance talk to every other one. What you could do, though is key the stream of split-out words by the actual word, and then use a (parallel) keyed, windowed `ReduceFunction` to get a list of distinct words in each key-group. Then you could have another `ReduceFunction` that isn't parallel that combines the results of the parallel ones. You'll want the second one to be windowed as well; `WindowFunctions` wait for all upstream operators to reach the correct Watermark before firing, so the windowing will make sure your non-parallel operator receives inputs from each of the parallel ones. The aggregation on the non-parallel operator is simple concatenation, since the keying at the beginning guarantees a given word will exist in exactly one parallel slot.

There's obviously a potential for a bottleneck at the single non-parallel operator, but the load scale with the total number of distinct words, which in practical terms is probably limited to something like 10k words or so just because of how English works.

Comment: I guess I didn't fully understand your answer. Could you please describe the operators and the order of them that you advise using?

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this solution using AggregateFunction.

```
public class WordDistinctCountAggregateWindowSocket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new WordDistinctCountAggregateWindowSocket();
    }

    public WordDistinctCountAggregateWindowSocket() throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

        // @formatter:off
        env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000)
                .flatMap(new SplitterFlatMap())
                .map(new SwapMap())
                .keyBy(new WordKeySelector())
                .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .aggregate(new DistinctCountAggregateFunction())
                .print();
        // @formatter:on

        String executionPlan = env.getExecutionPlan();
        System.out.println("ExecutionPlan ........................ ");
        System.out.println(executionPlan);
        System.out.println("........................ ");

        env.execute("WordDistinctCountAggregateWindowSocket");
    }

    public static class DistinctCountAggregateFunction
            implements AggregateFunction<Tuple2<Integer, String>, DistinctCountWithTimestamp, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 996334987119123032L;

        @Override
        public DistinctCountWithTimestamp createAccumulator() {
            System.out.println("createAccumulator");
            return new DistinctCountWithTimestamp(new HashSet<String>(), 0, System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        @Override
        public DistinctCountWithTimestamp add(Tuple2<Integer, String> value, DistinctCountWithTimestamp accumulator) {
            System.out.println("add");
            accumulator.distinctWords.add(value.f1);
            accumulator.distinctCount = accumulator.distinctWords.size();
            return accumulator;
        }

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> getResult(DistinctCountWithTimestamp accumulator) {
            System.out.println("getResult");
            String items = "";
            for (String item : accumulator.distinctWords) {
                items = items + item + "-";
            }
            return Tuple2.of(items, accumulator.distinctCount);
        }

        @Override
        public DistinctCountWithTimestamp merge(DistinctCountWithTimestamp a, DistinctCountWithTimestamp b) {
            System.out.println("merge");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class SplitterFlatMap implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3121588720675797629L;

        @Override
        public void flatMap(String sentence, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, 1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class SwapMap implements MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<Integer, String>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1392476272305784921L;

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, String> map(Tuple2<String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
            return Tuple2.of(value.f1, value.f0);
        }
    }

    public static class WordKeySelector implements KeySelector<Tuple2<Integer, String>, Integer> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2787589690596587044L;

        @Override
        public Integer getKey(Tuple2<Integer, String> value) throws Exception {
            return value.f0;
        }
    }

    public static class DistinctCountWithTimestamp {
        public Set<String> distinctWords;
        public Integer distinctCount;
        public long lastModified;

        public DistinctCountWithTimestamp() {
            this.distinctWords = new HashSet<String>();
            this.distinctCount = 0;
            this.lastModified = 0L;
        }

        public DistinctCountWithTimestamp(Set<String> distinctWords, Integer distinctCount, long lastModified) {
            this.distinctWords = distinctWords;
            this.distinctCount = distinctCount;
            this.lastModified = lastModified;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DistinctCountWithTimestamp [distinctWords=" + distinctWords + ", distinctCount=" + distinctCount
                    + ", lastModified=" + lastModified + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented my solution based on this example (https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_java/windows/HourlyTipsSolution.java)

```
public class WordDistinctCountProcessTimeWindowSocket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new WordDistinctCountProcessTimeWindowSocket();
    }

    public WordDistinctCountProcessTimeWindowSocket() throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        // env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        Time time = Time.seconds(5);

        // @formatter:off
        env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000)
                .flatMap(new SplitterFlatMap())
                .keyBy(new WordKeySelector())
                .timeWindow(time)
                .process(new DistinctProcessWindowFunction())
                .timeWindowAll(time)
                .reduce(new CountReduceFunction())
                .print();
        // @formatter:on

        String executionPlan = env.getExecutionPlan();
        System.out.println("ExecutionPlan ........................ ");
        System.out.println(executionPlan);
        System.out.println("........................ ");

        env.execute("WordDistinctCountProcessTimeWindowSocket");
    }

    public static class SplitterFlatMap implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3121588720675797629L;

        @Override
        public void flatMap(String sentence, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, 1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class WordKeySelector implements KeySelector<Tuple2<String, Integer>, String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2787589690596587044L;

        @Override
        public String getKey(Tuple2<String, Integer> value) throws Exception {
            return value.f0;
        }
    }

    public static class DistinctProcessWindowFunction
            extends ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>, String, TimeWindow> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -712802393634597999L;

        @Override
        public void process(String key,
                ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>, String, TimeWindow>.Context ctx,
                Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> values, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
            Tuple2<String, Integer> value = values.iterator().next();
            out.collect(Tuple2.of(value.f0, 1));
        }
    }

    public static class CountReduceFunction implements ReduceFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8047191633772408164L;

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> reduce(Tuple2<String, Integer> value1, Tuple2<String, Integer> value2)
                throws Exception {
            return Tuple2.of(value1.f0 + "-" + value2.f0, value1.f1 + value2.f1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Performance aspect, the best option is to use [HyperLogLog algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog).

Its Java implementation is described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hyperloglog).

And use the estimated cardinality of a large dataset as the accumulator in the aggregate function.